# While loop updation value

Tags: php, jquery

I am developing online attendance.But I stuck in while loop condition
I want to show my code first

```
<tbody>
        <?php
        $database = new Database();
        $db = $database->getConnection();
        $user = new User($db);
        $stmt = $user->atten();
        while($ro22 = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {

        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><input name ="uname" id ="uname" onBlur="checkAvailability2()" style ="border:none" value = "<?php echo $ro22['user_id'] ?>"/></td>
                <td><?php echo $ro22['first_name'] ?> <?php echo $ro22['last_name'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $ro22['parent_contact'] ?></td>

                <td><input type="button" value="<?php echo $ro22['ai'] ?>" id="pres" name="pres" onclick="return change(this);" onBlur="checkAvailability()" class="w3-button w3-teal"/></td>

            </tr>
        <?php } ?>

 </tbody>
```

This is output

[image: output]

**What I want**

> I want update present,absent value based on 101,102,103... value

I tried many but failed. Please help me out
Thanks in advance

Comment: You didn't understand my question I guess, I want to update value P,A based on 101,102...

Comment: So you want to update value when you click on the id ?

Comment: No,Actually above output is based on while loop. Please view this my query  ->  update atten_1 set ai='P' WHERE months = 'January' AND user_id ='101'");  each time 101 change to 102 in new row

Comment: What I want when I click A for 104 then P change to A in database

Comment: You're ID's are junk, `while(...){ .. <input id="pres" ... }` see an issue here? IDs are unique, clearly this one is not.  Second, where are these Javascript functions you call `onBlur="checkAvailability2()"` etc.  Third you have to submit something to the server to save it in the DB.  How do you plan to do that "magic" or the traditional form, maybe post it with "Ajax" ?

Comment: I tried to get value from each loop via onBlur="checkAvailability2()"
 <script>
function checkAvailability2() {
$("#loaderIcon").show();
jQuery.ajax({
url: "check_availability.php",
data:'pres='+$("#pres").val(),
type: "POST",
error:function (){}
});
}
</script>

Answer (score 0):

You need to place a call to the page on a click and pass the user_id. This is easy to do with jQuery:

```
function change(row) {
    $.post('thispage.php', { user_id: $(row).val() }, function(){ window.location.reload(); } );
}
```

And then receive the post in the PHP:

```
if (!empty($_POST['user_id'])) {
    /* toggle admission status */
}
```

After the request completes and the status is toggled, the page will reload.

Comment: This is assuming that $ro22['ai'] is some kind of id for the user. The value that is passed may need to be adapted.

Comment: I tried this concept look - <script>
function checkAvailability() {
$("#loaderIcon").show();
jQuery.ajax({
url: "check_availability.php",
data:'pres='+$("#pres").val(),
data1:'uname='+$("#uname").val(),
type: "POST",
error:function (){}
});
}
</script>    . I call this vaue and receive post value and used in other page.

Comment: In this way.     if(!empty($_POST["pres"])) {
  $database = new Database();
    $db = $database->getConnection();
 $query = $db->query("update atten_1 set ai='" . $_POST["pres"] . "' WHERE months = 'January' AND user_id = '101'");
        $query->execute();
 $r = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 echo $r > 0 ? 'exists' : 'available';

}

Comment: And $ro22['ai'] is not a user id . It is place where student particuler day of Attendance.

Comment: Like someone posted above, you cannot use the id pres on multiple elements on the page. You will also not be able to target the one that was clicked. You were passing the row with change(this), so you can target the element with $(row) to retrieve attributes using that configuration. You need a unique identifier... you can get the user id from the first td with $(row).parents('tr').find('input[name=uname]').val()

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general example. It's consisted of your `PHP` program (the `AJAX sender`) which I rewrote to be they way I think you wanted, a `javascript` file (containing the `AJAX` function) and another `PHP` file (the `AJAX request receiver`).

You can get different `use-cases` by altering the database query in the receiving `PHP` file.

**Javascript file (AJAX):**

```
// Send the `id` of the element
function checkAvailability(id)
{
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    // This `if` underneath is success. It means we got a response back
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
    {
      if(this.responseText == "OK")  
      {
          alert('ID: ' + id + ' changed. Response: ' + this.responseText);
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'The student has been updated.';
      }
      else if(this.responseText == "Not OK") 
      {
          alert('Something went wrong with id: ' + id);
      }
    }
  };
  // For example you send a request to attendance.php sending `id` info
  // - attendance.php just needs to echo the response to answer back
  xhttp.open("GET", "attendance.php?id=" + id, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

**Main PHP page (the file that sends the request):**

```
// U need jQuery to be able to send AJAX requests. Copy this, add to your html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<?php
  $database = new Database();
  $db = $database->getConnection();
  $user = new User($db);
  $stmt = $user->atten();

  echo '<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Student ID</th>
    <th>Student name</th>
    <th>Phone number</th>
    <th>Today\'s attendance</th>
  </tr>';
  while($ro22 = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
    echo '<tr>
      <td><input name ="uname" id ="uname" onBlur="checkAvailability2()" style ="border:none" value="'.$ro22['user_id'].'"/></td>
      <td>'.$ro22['first_name'].' '.$ro22['last_name'].'</td>
      <td>'.$ro22['parent_contact'].'</td>
      <td><input type="button" value="'.$ro22['ai'].'" id="pres" name="pres" onclick="change(this.id);" onBlur="checkAvailability(this.id)" class="w3-button w3-teal"/></td>
    </tr>';
   }
   echo '</table>';
?>
```

**The receiver file:**

```
 <?php
     $conToDatabase = ... // Here goes DB connection data

     if(isset($_GET['id']) && ctype_digit($_GET['id']))
     {
          $clean['id'] = $_GET['id'];
     }

     // Query your DB here using variable $clean['id'] as ID
     $querySuccess = ... 

     // if query successful echo 'OK';
     // else echo 'Not OK';
 ?>
```